# Pseudo polynomial or fast solution for the relaxed subset-sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, approximation

I have an array A of positive integers [a0, a1, a2, ..., an] and a positive number K. I need to find all (or almost all) pairs of subsets U and V of array A such as:

1. sum of all elements in U are less or equal to K
2. sum of all elements in V are less or equal to K
3. U + V may contain not all elements of original array A
4. all elements from U should come before all elements in V in initial array A. For example, let's imagine that we choose U = [a1, a3, a5] then we can start building array V only from a6. It is not allowed to use element a0, a2 or a4 in this case.

I was able to find DP solution, which is O(N^2 * K^2) (where N is total number of elements in A). Although N and K are small (< 100) it is still too slow.

I'm looking for some approximation algorithm or pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming algorithm. [Bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) problem looks similar to mine, but I'm not sure how I can apply it to my constraints...

Please advise.

EDIT: each number has upper bound equal to 50

Comment: If you want to find all pairs, is impossible to do it in n^2*k^2, because there could be exponential number of pairs.

Comment: I'm okay with "almost all" pairs of subsets for a given array... Looking into 0-1 Knapsack problem, but again - found it hard to apply to my case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: suppose K equals to sum of all elements of your input, now if you want to find even almost all pair, is impossible in polynomial time because, you can peak first element for the first set, and any subset from remaining items which means 2^n-1 possibility, I mean even for small values you can not expect average result in polynomial time. anyway you can show your algorithm by link to the http://ideone.com/. but number of possible pairs is another thing ... (not finding all of them just counting them).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, thanks for the explanation, you're right. But do you think I can find a good approximation algorithm for this problem? Just to note - I need not only the count, but exact subsets to process further. Also remember, there are several constraints which should reduce complexity of the problem - maximum sum K of the subset, order of elements (see cond. 4). Also N and K are pretty small... (still hoping to find solution for it)

Comment: @SaeedAmiri - here is my initial DP approach if you're interested: http://ideone.com/dOXFac

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, forgot to mention that each number in the array is no bigger than 50